# Debugging Puppet File Server

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm attempting to retrieve a file from puppet using the following:

```
file { '/etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml':
  ensure => 'present',
  source => file(
    "puppet:///private/etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml",
    "puppet:///public/etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml",
  ),
  require => Package['shibboleth'],
  notify => Service['shibd'],
}
```

This however gives me an error indicating that neither of the files could be found. In my `/etc/puppetlabs/fileserver.conf` I have the following:

```
[public]
  path /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/files/common
  allow *
[private]
  path /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/files/%H
  allow *
```

How would one go about debugging this?

Comment: Stop the master, run a WEBrick master using `puppet master --no-daemonize --debug --verbose` and initiate the agent run.

Comment: Could you please post the error message so we can help you thanks